# jQuery form not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am writing a basic form which requires validation. I cannot determine what I have missed that is causing the validation to be overlooked?

I have matched the tags but the ending tags at the bottom of the form don't look right.

Any help would be great!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<title>HTML Assignment</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        form2validation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#form2").validate({
                rules: {
                    fName: "required",
                    lName: "required",
                    sAddress: "required",
                    city: "required",
                    state: "required",
                },
                messages: {
                    fName: "Please enter your first name",
                    lName: "Please enter your last name",
                    sAddress: "Please enter your street address",
                    city: "Please enter your city",
                    state: "Please enter state",

                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

 $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.form2validation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="header">

<div id="content">

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
  <h1>
    Demographic Information Entry Screen
  </h1>

<p>
    <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" />

</p>
<p>
    <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" />

</p>
  <p>
    <label for="sAddress">Street Address:</label>
    <input name="sAddress" type="text" id="sAddress" size="30" maxlength="28" />

  </p>
<p>
    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="20" maxlength="20" />

    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <select name="state" size="1" id="state">
        <option value="State">State</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AR">AR</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
        <option value="TN">TN</option>
        <option value="TX">TX</option>
    </select>

  </p>
  <p>
  <legend> Gender: </legend> 
  <table width="200">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><label>
        <input type="radio" name="genderRG" value="radio" id="genderRG_0" />
        Male</label>        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="genderRG" value="radio" id="genderRG_1" />
        Female</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  </p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" style=margin-right: 30px />

    <input type="clear" name="clear" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick="" style=margin-right: 30px />

</p>
</form2 >
</Div>

</html>
```

Comment: ```</form2>``` is not from the original source but your attempt to match the tags, right?

Comment: @denoir - Im not sure I follow you. The form id="form2"

Comment: The end tag should be `</form>` not `</form2>`

Comment: You're also missing a bunch of `</div>` and `</body>` tags at the bottom. But most browsers will fill these in automatically when it sees `</html>`.

Comment: @Barmar - I fixed the </form> and added multiple tags, but it still does not validate?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: The horrifically bad JQUERY4U tutorial example again.  Lol.

Comment: Really it's bad code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Remove `novalidate="novalidate"` from the `form` tag.  This is not breaking anything but it's superfluous because the validation plugin dynamically adds this attribute.

2) Your `action` attribute is blank so when the form submits, it will not go anyplace.  Perhaps you already knew that.

3) The HTML markup for your two buttons is broken...

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" style=margin-right: 30px />
```

Your `style` attribute is missing its quotation marks and you don't need the `onclick` attribute.

4)  You don't need the `submitHandler` callback if it only contains `form.submit()` as that's the default.  Remove it and the `<form>` `action` attribute will be where the form submits.  Otherwise, you would use the `submitHandler` for your `ajax` code.

5)  Your closing `form` tag should be `</form>` and not `</form2 >`.

6)  Your "Clear" button is coded as `type="clear"`.  There is no such `type` as `clear`.  Change it to `type="button"` or `type="reset"`.

7)  Wrapping up everything like this is superfluous, unnecessary, verbose, and arcane...

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        form2validation: function()
        {
            $("#form2").validate({ .... });
        }
    }

    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.form2Validation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

It serves no useful purpose other than to cause more confusion to those seeking guidance.
  *It comes from a popular, yet poorly explained, [online demo/tutorial by Sam Deering](http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/) that is linked to/from many places.  IMO, if you're going to pass yourself off as a jQuery/JavaScript expert, at least use the code formatting style more commonly seen in JavaScript, and not the one used with PHP (Allman).  Whatever code formatting style you choose, at least be consistent with it throughout.*

**Exactly like any other jQuery plugin**, simply wrapping the `.validate()` method within the DOM ready event handler is more than adequate for proper initialization of this plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form2").validate({
        // any rules, options and callbacks
    })

});
```

I'm not sure which, if any, of those issues broke your form but it validates fine otherwise.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/uHN9W/**

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Let me explain, I am by no means an exert, the code you reference below is in there because I tried many things to get the validation to work with no success, read his tutorial and tried his code without success. For some reason, when I preview in chrome or safari, I still don't see the validation, but I do see it in the link you provided.                             It comes from a popular, yet poorly explained, online demo/tutorial by Sam Deering that is linked to/from many places. IMO, if you're going to pass yourself off as a jQuery/JavaScript expert,

Comment: @KevinSchultz, My comment about "jQuery expert" was directed at the tutorial author, not you.

Comment: I added some code for validation of the radio buttons so that 1 is selected for the valid form. I am evidently not doing it right, can you take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/kcschultz/uHN9W/1/

Comment: @KevinSchultz, why do you think it's not right?  Explain what you mean, because the `radio` buttons are being validated fine.  You also had some stray brackets I commented out:  http://jsfiddle.net/uHN9W/4/

Comment: For some reason in Dreamweaver, when I take out that bracket, it gives me an error which is why I left it in. As for the validation, I made a change likely right before you looked at it that allowed it to work, but the "Please enter your gender" message appears between the radio and the label?

Comment: @KevinSchultz, Those brackets are superfluous at best and invalid at worst.  Dreamweaver is simply wrong if it insists on keeping those brackets.  Keep in mind that Dreamweaver is irrelevant when code is deployed into the real world.  Also keep in mind that a WYSIWYG editor like Dreamweaver is not what most professional programmers would use to write JavaScript... we simply write valid code using a text editor.

Comment: @KevinSchultz, the default placement of the `label` when validating `radio` buttons is after the first `radio` in the group.  Please search the SO [tag:jquery-validate] tag for keywords `errorPlacement` and `radio` and you'll find dozens of solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Few things:

1. Closing tag of your form should be `</form>` and not `</form2>`
2. remove "novalidate"  attribut from the form tag so that it looks like this --

   ```
   <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
   ```